# Access an Array with both C++ and Python

Tags: python, c++, arrays

I am working on a simulation of a mini-galaxy consisting of about a 100,000 stars. The visual representation I want to do in Python, the large calculations in C++. Using ctypes, I am able to call a C++ function from Python.

What I basicly want is an array that is there in the RAM, that can be accessed both by python and C++. Then upon calling a function update() in python, C++ updates the array. It is important that C++ really only changes the values in the array. Copying it all the time would become quite time consuming.

I am quite a beginner, especially in C++, So I don't really know where to find the right information, and what keywords to use. Thoughts on how to do it are of course welcome, but some informational links would also be greatly appreciated.

Best,

Answer (score 1):

You can build C++ python wrapper module using the python C/C++ API:

https://docs.python.org/2/extending/extending.html

I would create a C++ module (`dataUpdater`) using python API offering a service, lets call it, `update` which should receive the Python object you want to load data into.

At your Python side I would call `dataUpdater.update` whenever I want to load the data from C++

**EDIT:**

Other option is to make your C++ module to behave like a data structure offering data access services such as:

- `getValueAt(index)`
- `setValueAt(index)`
- `getSize()`

And using it at python side:

```
for i in xrange(dataUpdater.getSize()):
    val = dataUpdater.getValueAt(i)
    ...
```

Comment: I have allready done so. I can also transfer values and arrays between C++ and Python. But how can I be sure the array doesn't get copied all the time it is sent from Python to C++ and back?

Comment: @renger In that case, use your C++ module as your data repository thus offering array access services instead an update method. For example: `getElementAtIndex(i)`, `getSize()`. This your C++ interface is more like a data structure itself.

Comment: @renger There are two solutions: you can keep all of the data on the C++ side, and call into it from Python each time you need it on the Python side, probably by implementing the sequence protocol for it.  (For a multi-dimensional array, this can be very complicated.)  Or you can use `numpy`, pass a `numpy` array as a single argument to your function, and use the buffer protocol to get the address of the (contiguous) data and its dimensions, and work on those on the C++ side.

Comment: I like the idea of the C++ module behaving as a data structure. I however want to generate the initial 'random' galaxy preferably with numpy. Is that still possible then? Or do I needlessly complicate everything?

Comment: @renger In that case you will need to update your "data structure" with the generated data which requires that a copy must be done unless your C++ implementation represents its contents in a numpy structure managed from C++ side using Numpy C API.

Comment: But then you are only talking about copying it once I guess? That wouldn't be a problem of course.

Comment: @renger Yes, just once.

Answer (score 1):

You should totally check the Python documentation on this issue:

https://docs.python.org/2/extending/

Having the doc in mind you can define a new Type; assuming that stars would be a double precision array:

```
typedef struct {
    PyObject_HEAD
    double * Stars;
} Galaxy;
```

Then define the Math operations method ... (python doc)

```
static PyObject* Galaxy_calc(Galaxy *self, PyObject *args)
{
     double * Star_temp;   

     /* Your Array is referenced by self->Stars*/
     Star_temp = self->Stars;

     /* Do the math in C++ */
     // All necessary calculations go here.
};
```

It is fairly easy to include these methods in the new type defined (Galaxy), you just have to set the variables:

```
static PyMethodDef Galaxy_methods[] = 
{
    {"calc", (PyCFunction)Galaxy_calc, METH_VARARGS,"Performs stelar calculations."},
    {NULL}  /* Sentinel */
};


static PyMemberDef Galaxy_members[] = 
{    {"Stars", T_OBJECT_EX, offsetof(Galaxy, Galaxy), 0, "Galaxy Stars"},
    {NULL}  /* Sentinel */
};
```

Now just include the Galaxy_methods var on the adequate position under

```
static PyTypeObject Galaxy_GalaxyType = {
    PyObject_HEAD_INIT(NULL)
    0,                         /*ob_size*/
    "Galaxy.Galaxy ",           /*tp_name*/
    sizeof(Galaxy),            /*tp_basicsize*/
    0,                         /*tp_itemsize*/
    (destructor)Galaxy_dealloc, /*tp_dealloc*/
    0,                         /*tp_print*/
    0,                         /*tp_getattr*/
    0,                         /*tp_setattr*/
    0,                         /*tp_compare*/
    0,                         /*tp_repr*/
    0,                         /*tp_as_number*/
    0,                         /*tp_as_sequence*/
    0,                         /*tp_as_mapping*/
    0,                         /*tp_hash */
    0,                         /*tp_call*/
    0,                         /*tp_str*/
    0,                         /*tp_getattro*/
    0,                         /*tp_setattro*/
    0,                         /*tp_as_buffer*/
    Py_TPFLAGS_DEFAULT | Py_TPFLAGS_BASETYPE,          /*tp_flags*/
    "Galaxy objects",          /* tp_doc */
    0,                         /* tp_traverse */
    0,                         /* tp_clear */
    0,                         /* tp_richcompare */
    0,                         /* tp_weaklistoffset */
    0,                         /* tp_iter */
    0,                         /* tp_iternext */
    Galaxy_methods,            /* tp_methods */
    Galaxy_members,            /* tp_members */
    0,                         /* tp_getset */
    0,                         /* tp_base */
    0,                         /* tp_dict */
    0,                         /* tp_descr_get */
    0,                         /* tp_descr_set */
    0,                         /* tp_dictoffset */
   (initproc)Galaxy_init,      /* tp_init */
    0,                         /* tp_alloc */
    Galaxy_new,                /* tp_new */
};
```

Use python documentation refered above to implement new, alloc, dealloc and init methods (these are quite simple) and it is done!

Comment: He'll also need accessor functions to access the array on the Python side.  (I suspect that it's easier to use `numpy`, and just one function in C++, which picks up the underlying memory of `numpy` and uses it.)

Comment: I am playing with Pablo Fransisco Perez' idea of using the C++ side as data structure. But creating an initial 'random' galaxy in python is just so much easier than in C++. After creating, I could probably pass it as a normal list, cause I don't really know whether ctypes supports numpy arrays as James Kanze pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

Doing this correctly is actually quite complicated.  First, you
should use the package `numpy` for the array in Python. Then,
you would define a C interface, as described in
https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/.  (This is a reference manual,
so you may want to read, and experiment with
https://docs.python.org/2/extending/index.html first.)  Most
importantly, you will want to use the buffer interface
(https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/buffer.html#bufferobjects)
to access the `numpy` arrays.

`ctypes` seems to have some support for contiguous arrays as
well, but I've no experience with it.  If you do any processing
of the arrays on the Python side, however, you'll want to use
`numpy`, which I don't think `ctypes` will support.

Comment: There will be no processing on the Python side, only initiation. I can just transform my random numpy array to a list if numpy isn't supported by ctypes. Since the initiation only has to be done once, speed is not an issue. 

I think the doc about the buffer interface is going to be quite helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how another proposal on how to accomplish this task, using Boost.Python.

Let's organize the code in 3 files: a `setup.py` to take care of compiling the extension code, a Python script that just uses the extension code, and the extension code itself:

```
.
├── galaxy.cpp
├── main.py
└── setup.py
```

`galaxy.cpp`: note that exceptions are not handled, so you can produce a segmentation fault by assigning to a Star that has not been initialized, and other C++ oddities. If you modify this code, take care to always name the BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE as the file itself.

```
#include <vector>

#include <boost/python.hpp>

class Star {
public:
    Star(double mass): mass(mass) {}

    bool set_mass(double given_mass) {
        this->mass = given_mass;
        return true;
    }
private:
    double mass;
};

class Galaxy {
public:
    Galaxy(const boost::python::list& masses) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < len(masses); i++) {
            double mass = boost::python::extract<double>(masses[i]);
            stars.push_back(Star(mass));
        }
    }

    bool update(int star_number, double mass) {
        return this->stars[star_number].set_mass(mass);
    }

private:
    std::vector<Star> stars;
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(galaxy)
{
    using namespace boost::python;
    class_<Galaxy>("Galaxy", init< boost::python::list >())
        .def("update", &Galaxy::update)
    ;
}
```

`setup.py`: note that Boost has been installed on my machine using Macports; you may need to adjust the path where it can be found, in the `include_dirs` variable.

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension

setup(name="galaxies",
      ext_modules=[
          Extension(
              "galaxy", ["galaxy.cpp"],
              include_dirs=["/opt/local/include"],
              libraries=["boost_python-mt"])])
```

Finally, use the `Galaxy` object to do whatever you need in `main.py`.  Note that in this example the object is constructed from a Python list (which means you are actually passing the array at least once between Python and C++), but this is not a must: you can have the C++ code read a file of data, and just pass its path from Python.

```
import galaxy

sombrero = galaxy.Galaxy([0.1, 22.3, 33.4])
sombrero.update(0, 24.5)
```

Here is how to compile and run the example:

```
$ python setup.py build_ext --inplace && python main.py
```

Answer (score 0):

And there is always this:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/python/doc/

"Welcome to version 2 of Boost.Python, a C++ library which *enables seamless interoperability* between C++ and the Python programming language."